# My form object does't work correctly

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm working on a complex form system...for me. I followed the instructions here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

My first class is (like Tag):

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints AS Assert;

class TipoPermessoFerie {

    protected $id;

    protected $nome;

    protected $descrizione;

    // permesso 'T' ferie 'F'
    protected $permesso;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($int) {
        $this->id = $int;
    }

    public function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setDescrizione($descrizione) {
        $this->descrizione = $descrizione;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescrizione() {
        return $this->descrizione;
    }

    public function setPermesso($permesso) {
        $this->permesso = $permesso;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPermesso() {
        return $this->permesso;
    }
}
```

The second class (like TagType):

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TipoPermessoFerieType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('nome');
        $builder->add('descrizione');
        $builder->add('permesso');
        $builder->add('id');
        //$builder->setMethod('GET');
        //$builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => '< Fase 2 >'));
        //$builder->add('reset', 'reset', array('label' => '< Annulla >'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TipoPermessoFerie',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'TipoPermessoFerie';
    }
}
```

The third class (like Task):

```
// src/appBundle/EntityForm/Form1
namespace AppBundle\EntityForm;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Form1 {
    protected $descrizione;
    protected $tipoPermessoFerie; // collezione di TipoPermessoFerie

    // metodi

    public function __construct(){
        $this->tipoPermessoFerie = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getDescrizione () {
        return $this->descrizione;
    }

    public function setDescrizione ($de) {
        $this->descrizione = $de;
    }

    // restituisce un ArrayCollection
    public function getTipoPermessoFerie () {
        return $this->tipoPermessoFerie;
    }

    public function setTipoPermessoFerie ($TPE) {
        $this->tipoPermessoFerie = $TPE;
    }
}
```

The fourth class (like TaskType):

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/Form1Type.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use AppBundle\EntityForm\Form1;

class Form1Type extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('descrizione');
        $builder->add('tipoPermessoFerie', 'collection', array('type' => new TipoPermessoFerieType()));
        $builder->setMethod('GET');
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => '< Fase 2 >'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'AppBundle\EntityForm\Form1',));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'form1';
    }
}
```

When i use these classes in the controller...

```
....
$f1 = New Form1 ();
    $f1->setDescrizione("Fase 1");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tipiF); $i++) {
        $f1->getTipoPermessoFerie()->add($tipiF[$i]);  //$tipiF[$i]);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new Form1Type(), $f1);
    dump($form->getData());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // poi bisogna validare la prima form e passare alla seconda
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $fe = New Ferie ();
        $dt = new \DateTime('now');
        //$dt->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));

        $fe->setDataRichiesta ($dt);
        $fe->setAnnoRif(date('Y'));
        $fe->setGiorniTurniChiesti(0);
        $fe->setDataDa($dt);
        $fe->setDataA($dt);
        dump($form->getData());
....
```

The first `dump()` during form preparation works, the second when I want to access data doesn't...why? I don't understand how can I use the form date in the controller...I need them to visualize in a second stage!

Did i lose something in my code?

I Explain... better...
It' seems there is non error in the form!
This is the dump of the errors... form errors is empty...

I can visualize the data object returned by dump command... but it's empty like this [dump($form->getData())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgR77.jpg)
This is the problem... This object must have 2 rows with values (not null) and i want to know whitch line is checked!

I'me trying to manage two forms in a single action is it correct?

**EDIT: Perhaps i'm not able to make me undertand... let's start from the original problem: i want to realize a 2 steps form (without javascrit and other client side program).... so i think to realize two form... One form gets some date by the user; the second form display the data obtained and asks other data to the user!
how can i do this?**

Comment: I notice that youre 'using' Doctrine:Annotations, but arent actually using them on your class params?  then later on in your question, youre using classes clearly intended as doctrine entities, but have no mappings in them.  Are those mapped externally? (eg orm files)

Comment: I use annotation also in the classes... i deleted those lines because in that way the code was too long, and i tought was not important.

Comment: Which one is the dump($form->getData()) corresponding to the image you posted : the first or the second?

Comment: The second! The firsth dump, in the previus section while building the firsth form, is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The `$form->isValid()` usually fails in two cases : the data in the request provoked errors or the form hasn't been submitted.

But I can be wrong and if that's because your form has errors, you can access them with : `$form->getErrors()`.

Edit: I was wrong. The submitted state of the form has no relation with the method used, it is just based on the fact that a form submission has caused the request or not.

Comment: Thiws is not possible the program executes the instructions in the isValid section!... so isValid() return TRUE!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved... this is not the good solution, it's a trick.

I use _GET['var'] to see the data returned by the first form.